# Do I need to explicitly del this object?

Tags: python

```
class Tokenizer()

def __init__(self):
   self.name = 'MyTokenizer'
   self.tokenizer = Language.create_tokenizer(nlp)

def __call__(self, text):
   if text:
      with CoreClient(timeout=60000) as client:
         doc = client.annotate(text, output_format='json')
   else:
      doc = Document("")

   ...
```

The question I am having is with the creation of 'CoreClient', which creates a http request to a server. The current code introduced by "with ... as client", can insure that the client is destroyed when 'client.annotate' is out of scope after it's done. However, the problem is that, the object 'client' has to be created for each request of processing 'text'. In order to avoid this, I had better create the object in the init method:

```
self.client = CoreClient(timeout=60000)
```

But then:

```
1) How to destroy the 'client' after all requests have been completed? OR
2) Is the current way of creating a Coreclient OK for each request? The creation of the object is heavy, which needs a lot of initialization.
```

EDIT:

```
def __enter__(self):
    self.start()
    return self

def start(self):
    if self.start_cmd:
        if self.be_quiet:
            # Issue #26: subprocess.DEVNULL isn't supported in python 2.7.
            stderr = open(os.devnull, 'w')
        else:
            stderr = self.stderr
        print(f"Starting server with command: {' '.join(self.start_cmd)}")
        self.server = subprocess.Popen(self.start_cmd,
                                       stderr=stderr,
                                       stdout=stderr)
```

To make it more clear, I added the implementation of the method **enter**. It seems it simply returns the object 'self'.

Comment: Why don't you just let python's default handling handle this? Your objects will be destroyed whenever the destructor for your obj is called

Comment: Is your `Tokenizer` going to always exist? Because once it is no longer referenced, then it will go away, and all of it's attributes will have their reference counts reduced by one, in which case `CoreClient` will also be reclaimed (assuming it isn't being referenced anywhere else). Note, you cannot delete *objects* in Python, there is no manual memory management

Comment: Even if you `del` the object, you are just deleting a reference to it. If there still exists other references to the object, then the object will still remain.I think the current way you're creating it is fine unless the `CoreClient` has a limit to the number of instances it can have for some reason.

Comment: @Chrispresso IOW, `del` doesn't delete *objects*, it deletes *names*

Comment: @rafaelc and Chrispresso: My major concern is for each request, the creation of CoreClint will take too much time, which is bad. It should be created once ideally.

Comment: `client` is the output of `CoreClient.__enter__`, not the instance of `CoreClient` (unless `__enter__` just does `return self` or something similar). `with self.client:` may be fine. It's hard to be sure, though, not knowing what `CoreClient` is or how it behaves as a context manager.

Comment: To answer the question in the title, it is almost *never* necessary to use `del`.

Comment: @chepner. I just tested, for multiple requests, it seems the CoreClient is only created once. I had thought it was created for each individual request.

Comment: With your current code, it is. The question is, does it *need* to be? My suggestion creates the instance of `CoreClient` once, but calls `CoreClient.__enter__` on that instance for each call to the `Tokenizer` instance.

Comment: @chepner. Please see the implementation of __enter__. Does it ensure the CoreClient will be only created once for multiple requests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to create the instance of `CoreClient` once. The `with` statement just ensures that the `__enter__` and `__exit__` methods of that instance are called before and after the body of the `with` statement; you don't need to create a new instance each time.

```
class Tokenizer()

    def __init__(self):
       self.name = 'MyTokenizer'
       self.tokenizer = Language.create_tokenizer(nlp)
       self.client = CoreClient(timeout=60000)  # Create client here

    def __call__(self, text):
       if text:
          with self.client:
             doc = self.client.annotate(text, output_format='json')
       else:
          doc = Document("")
```

It appears that `__enter__` and `__exit__` together spin up and tear down a new server each time the `CoreClient` instance is used as a context manager.

The client will be collected when the `Tokenizer` instance gets collected. However, unless you are in an active `with` statement, the `CoreClient` instance isn't doing anything.

Comment: Hi, Chepner: Unfortunately, I just tested and found that due to the statement 'with self.client' in the __call__ function, the CoreClient is created over and over again, which makes the system very slow, because the initialization of the system takes time. If I remove the 'with self.client', the system is initialized only once. But in this situation, the system won't close the http request after it's done, right?

Comment: To be precise, the `CoreClient` is *not* created over and over; you created it once, but the `__enter__` method *does* start a new server from scratch. If you want to use the same server across calls, you are going to have to reimplement how `CoreClient` works.

Comment: Basically, how to avoid the system is initialized multiple times in its current  form of code?

Comment: Given what you've shown, it looks like the only way would be to rewrite `CoreClient`, unless there is a way to start the server in `CoreClient.__init__` than set `self.start_cmd` to `None`.

Answer (score 1):

In this case I wouldn't worry about it because when the reference count goes to zero, Python will take care of it. Also, `del` does not actually delete and object. It might, but it might not. `del` will decrement the reference count to an object.

Take this for example:

```
In [1]: class Test:
   ...:     def __del__(self):
   ...:         print('deleted')
   ...:

In [2]: t = Test()

In [3]: del t
deleted

In [4]: t = Test()

In [5]: t1 = t

In [6]: del t  # Nothing gets printed here because t1 still exists

In [7]: del t1  # reference count goes to 0 and now gets printed
deleted
```

This is why I think you should just let Python handle the destruction of your objects. Python keeps track of objects reference counts and knows when they are no longer needed. So let it take care of that stuff for you.

Comment: `__del__` also may not *ever* be called, if the reason the object is going out of scope is because the interpreter is shutting down.

Comment: My major concern is for each request, the creation of CoreClint will take too much time, which is bad. It should be created once.